# Algorithm for read matrixes

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-series, code-complexity

An algorithm that need process a matrix `n x m` that is scalable.
E.g. I have a time series of 3 seconds containing the values: 2,1,4.
I need to decompose it to take a `3 x 4` matrix, *where 3 is the number of elements of time series and 4 the maximum value*. The resulting matrix that would look like this:

```
1   1   1
1   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
```

Is this a bad solution or is it only considered a data entry problem?
The question is,

**do I need to distribute information from each row of the matrix for various elements without losing the values?**

Comment: what is the logic behind populating the matrix?

Comment: Each line will be sent individually to a distribution network element. They do not have data dependency. Furthermore, the final sum is to be the series that was decomposed. 
A distributed system will generate requests based on this series.
So in the end, I need to have the original series. But this decomposition my algorithm is O (n ^ 2), which is unfeasible.

Comment: If you want to scale the solution to generate a NxM matrix, by definition, the complexity cannot go below O(n²).